# How to Create Optional Struct with Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I would like to create the following struct/array combination; however, I'm getting lost in the array nesting.  Is this the proper way to set up a "City", and if so, what would be the best practice technique to modify it, so that I can init new Cities with a different customer value?

Thanks!

```swift
struct City {
    var name: String
    var groceryStores: [GroceryStore]
}

struct GroceryStore {
    var name: String
    var employeesAtInterval = [employeeIDs]
}

var employeeIDs = [40, 20, 13, 44]
```

Comment: you are saying customer is a array of customer type, where have you define the customer type, customer is not a int. so if you need the number of customer then a int is what you need or the id of the customer then should be a array of int `var numberOfCostumer: [Int]` or `var numberOfCustomers = [Int]()`

Comment: Your code doesn't tell much about what you want to achieve, so you need to be more specific. What should your `City` struct and `GroceryStore` struct look like, and what are their purposes? How do you want to implement `customer`s? Your `customer` should be more than just `Int`s.

Comment: Thank you @JayLee ;  I updated the code to hopefully clarify a bit.  I'd like to create multiple of City, each with multiple of GroceryStore that can contain an array of employeeIDs, while the employeeIDs itself is an array of Ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, this seems like what you wanted to achieve:

```swift
struct City {
  var name: String
  var groceryStores: [GroceryStore]
}

struct GroceryStore {
  var name: String
  // As employeeIDs are Ints, you should initialize it using this syntax
  var employeesAtInterval = [Int]()
}

let employeeIDs1 = [40, 20, 13, 44]
let employeeIDs2 = [40, 20, 13, 44]
...
let groceryStore1 = GroceryStore(
  name: "store 1",
   employeesAtInterval: employeeIDs1
)
let groceryStore2 = GroceryStore(
  name: "store 2",
  employeesAtInterval: employeeIDs2
)
...
let city1 = City(name: "city 1", groceryStores: [groceryStore1, groceryStore2])
let city2 = City(name: "city 2", groceryStores: [groceryStore3, groceryStore4])
let cities = [city1, city2]
```

Comment: This looks really good.  Is there a way to edit/create the employeeIDs when a City is created?

Comment: You mean after a city instance is created? Or during instantiating it?

Comment: My apologies; I meant when instantiating.

Comment: Well, then you'd probably have to edit an instance of a GroceryStore, e.g. `groceryStore1`. Why not just provide proper ids when you make `employeeIDs1`?  Or are you trying to give automatic employeeIDs?

Comment: Or you can edit ids just after you created an instance--`city1.groceryStores[0].employeesAtInterval[0] = 31`, for example.

Comment: Glad that it helped :)